# Pressing slash (i.e /) suddently deletes text in bash

Tags: command-line, windows-10

I have been using ubuntu in windows without problems for some time. However all of sudden the slash (`/`) is just deleting text in a similar way to backspace. It is quite annoying because I cannot type `/` in the ubuntu terminal anymore. However, the slash is working perfectly in windows 10 apps such as the notepad. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you mean "backspace" instead of "backslash"?

Comment: Try asking this on Super User as they have more Windows experts - https://superuser.com. They may be able to help you better :) (Emphasis on the fact that I am ***not*** marking this as off-topic because this is perfectly valid here as well).

Comment: Does the problem persist if you restart your computer?

Comment: @user3091668 I recommend checking a Windows command prompt window and observe if the behavior occurs there (and testing with `cmd.exe` rather than PowerShell--the settings for a console created for `cmd.exe` is, by default, more similar to a WSL console). If so, the problem probably relates to the Windows console host, not WSL, Ubuntu, or bash. If not, run `cat` in a WSL window, type text in, and see if `/` backspaces in that. (Ctrl+C exits `cat`.) Then please **[edit]** this question to report your findings and also to say if restarting the computer, as user3140225 suggested, had any effect.